# Filtering dataframe based on latest time for each unique id, keeping all other data in the dataframe

Tags: python

How can I get the latest data of a unique id with respect to a particular column, let's say `year`, and keep all other columns in the dataframe?

Input:

[image: input]

Then output should be:

[image: output]

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. This question can be hard to understand, i recommend editting it with the tips inside the article: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following using `max`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['id','group'])['year'].max().reset_index()
```